# update UIProgressView from custom class get an error optional unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift

I getting crazy on this...hope you can help me.
What i want to do is updating a UIProgressView from my customClass called "myPDF" (there is a method to converting a PDF to graphics).

The UIProgressView should show the progress from the converting...
but i getting an fatal error:

"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

This is my customClass:

```
protocol DataEnteredDelegate {
    func loadingInformation (PDFprogress: Float, TextLabel: String)
}

class myPDF {

    var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate?

    var imageArray:[UIImage] = []
    var PDFname: String
    var progressPDF: Float = 0
        {
        didSet{
                let textconvert = String(progressPDF)
                delegate!.loadingInformation(progressPDF,TextLabel: textconvert)
                print("value from progressPDF: \(progressPDF)")
            }
        }
```

and thats my viewController.swift:

```
class initViewController: UIViewController, DataEnteredDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadingInformation(0, TextLabel: "0")  
    }

    func loadingInformation (PDFprogress: Float, TextLabel: String) {
        progressBar.progress = PDFprogress
        textLabel.text = TextLabel
        print(PDFprogress)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that you never set the delegate of your `myPDF` class instance (by the way, the class name should be `MyPDF`) and then you say `delegate!.loadingInformation()`; try `delegate?.loadingInformation(...`

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes you are rigth I don`t set the delegate, because i don´t know where i can set the delegate and how? I don´t have an segue only an button that call the func from my custom Class. Maybe you know it how i can set the delegate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you are right Kemal,

i updated my code, now i get the next problem...:( UIProgressView don´t update the bar over the time of the loop ist running.

CustomClass:

```
protocol DataEnteredDelegate {
    func loadingInformation (PDFprogress: Float, TextLabel: String)
}

var progressHolder: Float = 0.0

class MyPDF {

    var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate?

    var imageArray:[UIImage] = []
    var PDFname: String
    var progressPDF: Float = progressHolder
        {
        didSet{
            if (delegate != nil) {
                let textconvert = String(progressPDF)
                delegate!.loadingInformation(progressPDF,TextLabel: textconvert)
                print("value from progressPDF: \(progressPDF)")
            }
            }
        }

    init (imageArray: [UIImage], PDFname: String, progressPDF: Float, setDelegate: DataEnteredDelegate? ) {
        self.imageArray = []
        self.PDFname = PDFname
        self.progressPDF = progressPDF
        self.delegate = setDelegate
    }


    func numbersOfPages () -> Int {

        let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(PDFname, ofType: "pdf")!
        let url: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        let pdfDoc: CGPDFDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url)!
        let pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDoc) + 2

        return pageCount
    }

    func PDFtoImages () {
        let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(PDFname, ofType: "pdf")!
        let url: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
        let pdfDoc: CGPDFDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url)!
        let pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDoc)
        let firstPage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "firstPage")!
        let lastPage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "lastPage")!

        imageArray.append(firstPage)

        for index in 1...pageCount {
            let page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDoc, index)
            let pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, .MediaBox)

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pageRect.size, true, 0)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
            CGContextFillRect(context,pageRect)

            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

            CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
            let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            imageArray.append(img)
            progressPDF = progressPDF + 0.011
            progressHolder = progressHolder + 0.011
        }
        imageArray.append(lastPage)
        print("Funktion wurde ausgeführt die PDF mit dem Namen \(PDFname) wurde konvertiert")

    }
}

let PDF1 = MyPDF(imageArray: [], PDFname: "mining", progressPDF: progressHolder, setDelegate: nil)
let PDF2 = MyPDF(imageArray: [], PDFname: "MiningAndTunneling", progressPDF: progressHolder, setDelegate: nil)
```

viewController class:

```
class initViewController: UIViewController, DataEnteredDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func loadingInformation (PDFprogress: Float, TextLabel: String) {
        progressBar.progress = PDFprogress
        textLabel.text = TextLabel
        print(PDFprogress)
    }

    @IBAction func startRoot(sender: AnyObject) {
        PDF1.delegate = self
        PDF1.PDFtoImages()
        PDF2.delegate = self
        PDF2.PDFtoImages()
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("startRoot", sender: self)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok now it works used the Multithreading to get parallel update....keyWord Grand Central Dispatch

Comment: Tom is right, UIProgressView is a member of UIKit framework which is not thread safe. You should update your progress on main thread. Try this;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.progressBar.progress = PDFprogress
}

Answer (score 0):

Not clear, where is you get this error, but check your "implicity unwrapped optionals" – variables with exclamation marks.
One or more, is not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Suspicious on this line

`delegate!.loadingInformation(progressPDF,TextLabel: textconvert)`

There's no where in the code, indicating you set the delegate to anything, probably should be view controller.

Normally for delegates, use `delegate?`

Answer (score 0):

You set your `delegate` object optional but never initialized it so it's definetely nil. In your `initViewController` classes `viewDidLoad` method use this;

```
let pdfClass = myPDF()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pdfClass.delegate = self
    loadingInformation(0, TextLabel: "0")  
}
```

Then check your delegate is **not** nil;

```
var progressPDF: Float = 0
        {
        didSet{
                let textconvert = String(progressPDF)
                if let delegate = delegate {
                    delegate.loadingInformation(progressPDF,TextLabel: textconvert)
                }
                print("value from progressPDF: \(progressPDF)")
            }
        }
```